# Why does my httpget doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello everyone : I'm creating an ASP.net project, here is the folder with a problem :

```
Dashboard :
--> DashboardIndex.cshtml
--> DashboardPage.cs
--> DashboardPageModel.cs
```

My page generates the following code

```
<div class="small-box bg-aqua">
    <div class="inner">
        <h3>@Model.OpenOrders</h3>
        <p>Open Orders</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
       <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
    </div>
    <a href="/IP/1/11_2" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

I click on the button, what leads me to `http://localhost:21739/IP/1/11_2`

Aaand.. Error 404 !

Yet, I coded what seems to be the appropriate function (I compared with another function I code (which works) and I didn't find any relevant differences)

```
namespace Serene7.Common.Pages
{
    using Serenity;
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Serenity.Data;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    [RoutePrefix("Dashboard"), Route("{action=index}")]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize, HttpGet, Route("~/")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(MVC.Views.Common.Dashboard.DashboardIndex, new DashboardPageModel());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("IP/{Station=0}/{Timestp=0}")]
        public ActionResult IP(int station, string timestp)
        {
            timestp = timestp.Replace("_", ":");
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDb)\MSSqlLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=Serene7_Default_v1");
            List<string> listeIps = new List<string>();

            string listDb = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT (IpSource) FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE Station = '{0}' AND TimeStp = '{1}';",station,timestp);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn);
            string listDb2 = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT (IpSource,IpDestination) FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE Station = '{0}' AND TimeStp = '{1}';", station, timestp);
            SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(listDb2, myConn);
            myConn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                listeIps.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();

            SqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                listeIps.Add(reader2[0].ToString());
            }

            List<string> noRepetitions = listeIps.Distinct().ToList();



            int lengthList = noRepetitions.Count;
            byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[400 * lengthList * lengthList * 4];

            string listDb3 = string.Format("SELECT SUM(ToTheRight) FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump]  WHERE IdSource = @IdSource AND IdDestination = @IdDestination AND Station = '{0}' AND TimeStp = '{1}';", station, timestp);
            string listDb4 = string.Format("SELECT SUM(ToTheLeft) FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE IdDestination = @IdSource AND IdSource = @IdDestination AND Station = '{0}' AND TimeStp = '{1}';", station, timestp);

            SqlCommand myCommand3 = new SqlCommand(listDb3, myConn);
            SqlCommand myCommand4 = new SqlCommand(listDb4, myConn);

            IDbDataParameter param;



            param = myCommand3.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@IdDestination";
            param.Value = "''";

            param = myCommand3.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@IdSource";
            param.Value = "''";

            param = myCommand4.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@IdDestination";
            param.Value = "''";

            param = myCommand4.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@IdSource";
            param.Value = "''";

            int[,] matrix = new int[lengthList, lengthList];

            for (int x = 0; x < lengthList; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < lengthList; y++)
                {
                    myCommand3.Parameters["@IdSource"].Value = "'" + noRepetitions[x] + "'";
                    myCommand3.Parameters["@IdDestination"].Value = "'" + noRepetitions[y] + "'";
                    myCommand4.Parameters["@IdSource"].Value = "'" + noRepetitions[x] + "'";
                    myCommand4.Parameters["@IdDestination"].Value = "'" + noRepetitions[y] + "'";

                    int total = 0;

                    SqlDataReader reader3 = myCommand3.ExecuteReader();
                    SqlDataReader reader4 = myCommand4.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader3.Read())
                    {
                        total += (int)reader[0];
                    }
                    reader3.Close();
                    while (reader4.Read())
                    {
                        total += (int)reader[0];
                    }
                    reader4.Close();
                    matrix[x, y] = total;
                }
            }

            int maximum = matrix.Cast<int>().Max();
            double logMax = Math.Log(maximum);

            for (int x = 0; x < 20 * lengthList; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 20 * lengthList; y++)
                {
                    int posX = x % 20;
                    int posY = y % 20;
                    int offset = ((20 * lengthList * 4) * y) + (x * 4);
                    int test = 0;
                    if (matrix[x, y] > 0)
                    {
                        test = 1;
                    }
                    int value = (int)(test * (10 + (245 * Math.Log(matrix[x, y]) / logMax)));
                    imageBuffer[offset] = (byte)value;
                    imageBuffer[offset + 1] = (byte)value;
                    imageBuffer[offset + 2] = (byte)value;
                    imageBuffer[offset + 3] = 255;
                }
            }
            unsafe
            {
                fixed(byte* ptr = imageBuffer)
                {
                    using (Bitmap image = new Bitmap(256, 100, 256 * 4,
                       PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb, new IntPtr(ptr)))
                    {
                        image.Save(@"C:\Users\FS091843\Desktop\Stations\Station1\greyscale.png");
                    }
                }
            }
            DashboardPageModel dashboard = new DashboardPageModel();
            return View(MVC.Views.Common.Dashboard.DashboardIndex, dashboard);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea of what is going wrong ?

Comment: What happens if you try `http://localhost:21739/Dashboard/IP/1/11_2`?

Comment: It works ^^ ! ty !